# Get boolean value from realtime database Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I need to take the value of a boolean variable, but I can't specify that the local variable is a boolean. How can I do that?

```
var value = dbRef.Child("Values").Child("updateIsReady").GetValueAsync();
if(value)
{
    //something is happening
}
```

Try to implement my application's update check through a variable in the database that changes when an update is released

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). I also recommend reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the best chances that someone here can help.

Comment: *but I can't specify that the local variable is a boolean* - why not? Where's the code you attempted to perform that function? You may also want to review [Reading Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start). There are many examples here on SO on how to work with snapshots, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144833/how-to-use-datasnapshot-with-firebase-for-unity) or maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52770003/how-to-download-data-from-firebase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the value once its ready in `task.IsCompleted`:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Values")
.GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {

if (task.IsFaulted) {
// Handle the error...
}

else if (task.IsCompleted) {

//get the data here:

//this is snapshot of the reference
DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

//this is your boolean, you get it from the snapshot
bool updateIsReady = snapshot.Child("updateIsReady").Value;

}
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. After explicitly converting and running the project, I get Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Error

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: "The application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way"

Comment: Can you do some logs to check which line is causing this error?

Comment: This error appears every other time when starting Play Mode (maybe because this method performed called at start). 
I call the method on clicking the button, the window with the error appears after the second click.

Comment: Log with variable: False
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
FirebaseInitialization/<>c:<CheckUpdate>b__3_0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Firebase.Database.DataSnapshot>) (at Assets/Scripts/Data/FirebaseInitialization.cs:44)
Firebase.Extensions.TaskExtension/<>c__DisplayClass4_1`1<Firebase.Database.DataSnapshot>:<ContinueWithOnMainThread>b__1 ()
Firebase.Dispatcher/<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1<bool>:<RunAsync>b__0 ()
Firebase.ExceptionAggregator:Wrap (System.Action)
Firebase.Dispatcher:PollJobs ()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update ()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseMonoBehaviour:Update ()

Comment: the log outputs false even when I change the value of the variable in the database to true

Comment: Did you set up firebase and initialized everything like the documentation says?

Comment: I solved this problem by updating the firebase page. Thanks)

Comment: Okay great GoodLuck.

Answer (score 0):

bool value = bool.Parse(dbRef.Child("Values").Child("updateIsReady").GetRawJsonValue());

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).